# Spark scala - Dataframe - Convert Schema Text file (input) to complex Json schema (output)

Tags: arrays, json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have input and output schemas as below. I'm new to spark and scala. Can someone help me to convert the dataframe that loads the text file and finally convert it to land json file.

**INPUT**

```
    val OTBCleanFile: Array[StructField] = Array(
          StructField("varbl_1_txt", StringType, true),
          StructField("varbl_2_txt", StringType, true),
          StructField("varbl_3_txt", StringType, true),
          StructField("varbl_4_txt", StringType, true),
          StructField("varbl_5_txt", StringType, true),
          StructField("varbl_6_txt", StringType, true),
          StructField("varbl_7_txt", StringType, true),
          StructField("varbl_8_txt", StringType, true),
          StructField("varbl_9_txt", StringType, true),
          StructField("varbl_10_txt", StringType, true),
          StructField("varbl_11_txt", StringType, true),
          StructField("varbl_12_txt", StringType, true),
          StructField("varbl_13_txt", StringType, true),
          StructField("varbl_14_txt", StringType, true),
          StructField("varbl_15_txt", StringType, true),
          StructField("email", StringType, true))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
val JsonFileScma = (new StructType)
  .add("col1",  (new StructType)
    .add("col2",  StringType)
    .add("col3",  StringType)
    .add("col4",  StringType)
    .add("col5",  StringType)
    .add("col6",  StringType)
    .add("col7",  StringType))
  .add("email", (new StructType)
    .add("type", StringType)
    .add("value", StringType))
  .add("templateId", StringType)
```

Mapping can be one to one and leave few fields from input file/schema.

Thank you in Advance,
Regards,
Dattu

Comment: What have you tried? Is `dataset.map` not working?

Comment: Reading file: /* Reading OTB File iso-8859-1 */

    val delimiter2 = "\307"

    val OTBInputDF = sqlc.read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("header", "false") // Use first line of all files as header
      .option("delimiter", delimiter2)
      .option("charset","iso-8859-1")
      .schema(StructType(OTBCleanFile))
      .load("OTBCleanFile.dat")

    OTBInputDF.show()
    OTBInputDF.printSchema()

Comment: val data = OTBInputDF.selectExpr(few fields)  data.write
      .format("json")
      .save("OTBInputDF.json")                                                                                  But it's not really the output Json format I want

Answer (score 0):

****Working Code****

```
    // Initialize

    val conf = new                                                              
    SparkConf().setAppName("process_text_to_json").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlc = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)    

// Reading File iso-8859-1

val delimiter = "\307"
val OTBInputDF = sqlc.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "false") // Use first line of all files as header
  .option("delimiter", delimiter)
  .option("charset","iso-8859-1")
  .schema(StructType(OTBCleanFile))
  .load("cln.dat")

  // Convert to Json

  val data = OTBInputDF.selectExpr("varbl_1_txt as col1"  ,"varbl_1_txt as col2","varbl_1_txt as col3","varbl_1_txt as col4","varbl_1_txt col5","email as col6")

  val data2 = data.select(to_json(struct(col("col1"),col("col2"),col("col3"),col("col4"),col("col5"))) as "clientTag",col("col6"))
  data2.show()
  data2.printSchema()
```